# Prove all finite metric space is discrete

Tags: metric-spaces

> Can a finite continue subset $M$ be a non discrete metric space $(M,d)$?

I need help here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space is finite. Let $S$ denote the set of all distance between any two distinct points in $M$. This set is finite since $M$ is, and it has a minimum, denote this minimum by $r$. The collection of open balls of radius $r/2$ is a collection of open sets (it's actually an open cover) which are all disjoint. Thus $M$ is discrete, since all of the points of $M$ are open (they are the only elements of the open balls described above).

Comment: Would you mind upvoting and clicking the check mark under my answer then? Unless it wasn't satisfactory.

Comment: By the way. Any good book to learn more, the book I´m using isn´t very detailed. Thanks

Comment: Topology by Munkres is a great place to start. If you're short on cash, Topology by Willard is an almost equally well written book, but it will prepare you more for functional analysis rather than general topology.